# Any free couchbase store available online for learning purposes?

Tags: couchbase

I'm looking for an online couchbase data store to learn about this product.

Indeed, trying to install the community edition failed as the installer required my 64 bist laptop to have 4 cores, when it only has 2 of them.

Comment: I think for development and PoC having 2 cores instead of 4 just brings a warning, but you can still make it run, can't you?

Comment: It stopped the install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I don't think you will manage to find a free Couchbase hosting in the near future, as it requires too much system resources. But I can suggest using Amazon Web Services, which has the Couchbase Comumnity Server at [Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B016CM4KP0/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-7&qid=1448043866608). You can deploy it on m3.medium EC2 instance with the price of $0.067/hr which will just cost you a 0.5 $ per day (8 working hours).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are using your Couchbase Server for, you can even run a Couchbase Server instance on an AWS t2.micro, which is free if you sign up for the year's worth of free tier.

I am currently happily running a node of Couchbase Server 4.0 on a t2.micro, it is only serving ~10 operations a second and does not make use of views, XDCR or N1QL but this should be sufficient if you are only using it to learn how it works and what you can do it/the SDKs.

Comment: Without views and n1ql there is no way you will learn what you can do with it, basically because you will not be able to get data by secondary indexes. It will be just used as Key Value store, but not as fully functional Document Store.